# django, path parameter in form don't work

Tags: python, django, forms, url, path

My path looks like so:
`path('edit/<str:entry_name>/', views.edit, name='edit')`.

I want to access this path through a form like so:

```
<form action="{% url 'edit' entry_name=entry_title %}" method="get">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="hidden" name="title" value="{{ entry_title }}">
    <input type="hidden" name="content" value="{{ entry_content }}">
    <input type="submit" value="Edit">
</form>
```

But then I get this error: `Reverse for 'edit' with keyword arguments '{'entry_name': ''}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['edit/(?P<entry_name>[^/]+)/\\Z']`.

It seems like `entry_name` is empty, but I use the `entry_name` parameter elsewhere on the page and it works fine.

```
{% block title %}
    {{ entry_title }}
{% endblock title %}
```

is not empty, since I can see the titel on the tab-title.

EDIT:
Here are the views:
To access the entry page where the form is located:

```
def entry(request, title):
    entry = util.get_entry(title)
    if entry is None:
        return render(request, "encyclopedia/error.html", {
            "error_name": "Not Found",
            "error_message": f"{title} page Not Found"
        })
    return render(request, "encyclopedia/entry.html", {
        "entry_title": title,
        "entry_content": markdown2.markdown(entry)
    })
```

The edit view:

```
def edit(request, entry_name):
    if request.method == "POST":
        query_dict = request.POST
        new_entry_name = entry_name
        content = query_dict.get("content")
        util.save_entry(new_entry_name, content)
        entry = util.get_entry(new_entry_name)
        if entry is not None:
            return HttpResponseRedirect(f"/wiki/{new_entry_name}/")
        else:
            return HttpResponse("Oop something went wrong there")
    return render(request, "encyclopedia/entry.html", {
        "error": "",
        "title": entry_name,
        "content": request.GET.get("content")
    })
```

Comment: Can you share the full error traceback? Also try to print what is inside `entry_title`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to change your form action bcs i`ve never seen someone doing '=' while giving an id or slug in action

try this:

```
<form action="{% url 'edit' entry_title %}" method="get">
```

And btw can you add your models and views.py for better understanding

Comment: I also tried that, I get this error: ```Reverse for 'edit' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['edit/(?P<entry_name>[^/]+)/\\Z']```

Comment: add your model pls

Comment: I dont rlly have a model yet. I only use the urls.py, views.py and html templates. But i am also a beginner in django and python.

Comment: So how are you going to add name or slug or pk in your urls.py?

Comment: Listen you need a model better use slug for what you`re trying to do btw its gotta be unique and after that you need to show your main page which you can edit by this slug

And onl after that you can send slug into your form action in template

Comment: By in my app folder I use the urls.py class and add paths to it. Not sure what slug or pk is, but i add the name like so: ```path('edit/<str:entry_name>/', views.edit, name='edit')```

Comment: You need to learn about models to start doing that

Slug or pk (primary key) using for identification of different page like: localhost/1/1, localhost/1/2